# Get a document name based in the rules

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-security

I'm searching to add a rule in my Firestore database.
The rule is to allow write documents if the document equal the `request.auth.uid`.
I don't know how to search the name of my document in the rules.

This is my code where is missing this part :

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /users/{anyDocument} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == ?????????;
      allow read
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unclear in your question, but I'm assume you want to enforce only writing a document who's id is equal to the users auth id.

`match /users/{anyDocument} {`

Because of this line, the document id will be set to the variable `anyDocument`, so this is what you want to check.

`allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == anyDocument;`